# jquery scrollTo() {axis:'x'} don't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

i dont know what i'm doing wrong, but if i put the option `{axis:'x'}` on this plugin, the scroll don't work

my html code:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="main" class="container">

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="mask">

                <div id="item0" class="item">
                    <a name="item0"></a>
                    <div class="conteudo">
                        aaaa
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="item1" class="item">
                    <a name="item1"></a>
                    <div class="conteudo">
                        bbbbs
                    </div>
                </div>          

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>



<div class="wrap_menu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#item1" class="panel">EMPRESA</a></li>
                <div class="traco"></div>
                <li><a href="#item2" class="panel">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
                <div class="traco"></div>
                <li><a href="#item3" class="panel">EVENTOS</a></li>
                <div class="traco"></div>
                <li><a href="#item4" class="panel">VJ</a></li>
                <div class="traco"></div>
                <li><a href="#item5" class="panel">PARCEIROS</a></li>
                <div class="traco"></div>
                <li><a href="#item6" class="panel">CONTATO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

my css code:

```
html, body, #wrap {height: 100%;}

body > #wrap {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}

body{
    font-family:'Pontano Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#110030 url(../imagens/fundo_site.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 117px;}  /* deve ter a mesma altura do rodapé */
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:#ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#mask {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*background:#FFCC00;*/
}

.item {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}

#item0{
    background: #000 url(../imagens/bkg/fundo_site.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#item1{
    background: #000 url(../imagens/bkg/fundo_site2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.conteudo {
    position:relative;
    width:960px;
    height:420px;
    margin: 0 auto 150px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-480px;
    background:url(../imagens/fundo_conteudo.png);
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}

.item:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.conteudo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

my script code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('a.panel').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //reset and highlight the clicked link
            $('a.panel').removeClass('ativo');
            $(this).addClass('ativo');

            //grab the current item, to be used in resize function
            current = $(this);

            //scroll it to the destination
            //$('.item').hide();
            //$((this).attr('href')).add('.current').show();
            //$('.item').show();
            $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 2000,{axis:'y'});


        });

    });
```

i try too to use this way:

```
$('#wrapper').animate({scrollLeft:$(this).attr('href')},2000);
```

but don't works too!

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: So you can't animate to some random string from the href? Funny. Try using an actual number when using animate() and it will work. As for the plugin, I have no idea!

Comment: humm, i think i don't understand what you mean. "Try using an actual number", what number?

Comment: Exactly, what number, you're trying to animate the scrollLeft property to `#item2`, how do you expect that to work with a property that accepts numbers.

Comment: humm.. ok, but how to animate the entire view to left position? like a "panel scroll" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic functionality, try replacing

```
$('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 2000,{axis:'y'});
```

with

```
$('#wrapper').scrollLeft($($(this).attr('href')).offset().left);
```

This code should get set the scroll correctly. In order to animate the panel to slide to this position, try this code:

```
$('#wrapper').animate({scrollLeft: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().left}, 2000);
```

EDIT:

In the case of your site, the elements are above and below each other. Currently, you can use this code in order to cause a transition:

```
$('#wrapper').animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 2000);
```

There are CSS and site-structure changes you can make to cause the transition to occur via a left-scroll, and to make only the content within the black centered box make the transition. Let me know if this kind of functionality is what is intended, and I'll provide for you some example markup.

Comment: i try the last option ... nothing happens.. you could see here: http://www.alsite.com.br/lukas/

Comment: Looking at your site, the elements are splayed differently then when I put your markup and code in jsfiddle. You can't use scrollLeft in order to animate this transition because the next element is BELOW the previous element. you can use scrolTop and offset().top instead; I'll edit my response as I get a more suitable mockup

Comment: hum.. so.. how i can put this code aside and not below the previous element? i set the property on css `.item{ float:left}`

Comment: yeah, i want the transition on `x` axis, intead the current. But i will have diferent background for each item on menu. I need the same effect that i have on site now, but the transition on horizontal way..

Comment: It's difficult for me to verbally explain why they can't render next to each other how it's currently set up. The html and css needs to be revised so that the viewable area is anchored within the page, and there is a container div underneath it which contains all your content elmenents. These content elements would have your #item tags assigned to them. Each content element would need to be assigned css that would limit its width to the width of your viewable area. You would then scroll the container div to display the corresponding #item elements.

Comment: hum.. ok... i will try some modifications on css. Thanks for your help!